# Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) (django)

Tags: python, json, django

hello I am getting this error and I don't know how to solve it please help
this is my traceback:
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/update/

```
Django Version: 3.1.6
Python Version: 3.6.8
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'billing',
 'accounts',
 'products',
 'orders',
 'search',
 'tags',
 'carts',
 'addresses']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

During handling of the above exception (0), another exception occurred:
  File "C:\Users\daghe\Dev\ecommerce - Backup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\Dev\ecommerce - Backup\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\daghe\Dev\ecommerce - Backup\src\carts\views.py", line 28, in updateItem
    data = json.loads(request.body)
  File "c:\python36\lib\json\__init__.py", line 354, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "c:\python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "c:\python36\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
```

Exception Type: JSONDecodeError at /cart/update/
Exception Value: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

and this is my view

```
def cart(request):
    data = cartData(request)

    cartItems = data['cartItems']
    order = data['order']
    items = data['items']

    context = {'items':items, 'order':order, 'cartItems':cartItems}
    return render(request, 'carts/home.html', context)


def updateItem(request):
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    productId = data['productId']
    action = data['action']
    print('Action:', action)
    print('Product:', productId)

    customer = request.user.customer
    product = Product.objects.get(id=productId)
    order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)

    orderItem, created = OrderItem.objects.get_or_create(order=order, product=product)

    if action == 'add':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity + 1)
    elif action == 'remove':
        orderItem.quantity = (orderItem.quantity - 1)

    orderItem.save()

    if orderItem.quantity <= 0:
        orderItem.delete()
```

return JsonResponse('Item was added', safe=False)

Comment: JSON response is causing the issue. Your return value isn't a valid JSON object/data type. Try `return JsonResponse({"added": "item was added"})`

Comment: thx but now i am getting "User has no customer." from request.user.customer